# git - push to gitlab from local git server

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, webhooks, hexo

i have a local git server where i host files for a docker container with a blogging software (hexo).
After a push to the local git server, i would like to automatically push the blog to gitlab.

This is the directory i push to the local git server:

```
hexo                    << to remote
 - scaffolds            << to remote
 - source               << to remote
 - themes               << to remote
 - _config.yml          << to remote
 - package.json         << to remote
 - README.md            << to remote
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
README.md
```

The directory hexo contains the blog.
The lines that end with `<<to remote` are thoose that i want to push to gitlab also.

Is this maybe possible with git webhooks, e.g with a post-recieve hook on my local git server? If so, how? I coudnt find a good tutorial about it.
I only want to push the folder hexo with its content to gitlab, not the whole repository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> git webhooks, e.g with a post-receive hook on my local git server?

Not exactly: a git webhook is *not* a post-receive hook.

- A webhook is an http listener, which listen to event sent by a remote hosting service like GitLab (typically, a push event).
- A [`post-receive` hook is a server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks), triggered by a git push to that *same* server.

In your case, a `post-receive` hook is what you need, if you have the control to the Git server you are pushing to.
In your server, make an executable `/path/to/repo.git/hooks/post-receive` and do a `git push` to gitlab there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have control of the of the local git server. Do i have to ssh into my git server and place the post-recieve hook there ( data/git/repositories/jsus/hexo-docker.git/hooks/) or can i also place it in the hexo-docker repo on my computer from where i initially push?

Comment: You need to ssh to the server: a hook is never pushed.

Comment: Thanks again VonC! I have a post-recieve hook now and its getting triggerd everytime i push to my local git server. But there is an issue with authentication, how should i handle this? Ideally, i would like to use ssh keys. Can i use the ssh key of the user pushing to the local git server (since he can also authenticate with the gitlab repo)?

Comment: @jsus it is best to *not* reuse an existing ssh key of another user, since that would mean copying the *private* key... which would therefore no longer be private. Generate one in the user account running Git on the server. And copy the new public key to the GitLab remote user account SSH setting page.